# d3js Aster Plot label text wrapping

Tags: jquery, d3.js, aster

We are currently designing Aster Plot using D3Js. There is a requirement to wrap label text with orientation. The orientation is achieved but issues with wrap. Now it looks like [Current Aster Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGrbJ.jpg) and the output should look like as shown in [Output Aster Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLKXB.jpg)

**Code Snippet**

```
 var outerGroup = svg.selectAll(".solidArc")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append("g");

 var text = outerGroup.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                var rotation = computeTextRotation(d);
                if (rotation.correction >= 180) {

                    var midAngle = d.endAngle < Math.PI ? d.startAngle / 2 + d.endAngle / 2 : d.startAngle / 2 + d.endAngle / 2 + Math.PI;
                    return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d)[0] + "," + labelArc.centroid(d)[1] + ") rotate(-90) rotate(" + (midAngle * 180 / Math.PI) + ")";
                }
                else {
                    return "rotate(" + rotation.global + ")" + "translate(" + (radius + innerRadius) / 2 + ",0)" + "rotate(" + -rotation.correction + ")";
                }
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "right")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.data.label;
            });

 function computeTextRotation(d) {
        var rotation = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
        return {
            global: rotation,
            correction: rotation > 90 ? 180 : 0
        };
    }
```

Comment: There is no value `right` for text-anchor. It has to be `start`, `middle` or `end`. In your case, it should be `end`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3js aster plot label display as arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717564/d3js-aster-plot-label-display-as-arc)

Comment: Thanks Gerardo Furtado, We have tried with “end” instead of “right”, but output is not as expected. Please refer to output
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Vs4agcJ5eqMtq0xV16o_tHp97rnDDdJd